# Notepad++ 2nd file opens very slow

Tags: notepad++

I am working with a number of large text files. On my reasonably fast system, even a 100 MB .csv file opens in Notepad++ in less than a second.

However, if I load a 10 MB file (unnoticable open time) and then a second 0.1 MB file, it takes about 10 seconds!
Funny thing: If I open a third file, the open time depends on the size of the currently shown file.

I use Notepad++ 7.9. I also tried older Notepad++ versions, same behavior. Same Notepad++ on Machine running a different windows, all is fine.

Unfortunately Notepad++ requires social media account to report errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some information whether the text files are stored locally or on a network drive.

Comment: Stored on a local SSD. If it was the network, then the order of opening would not have mattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I uninstalled my extensions

- XML Tools
- Npp XML Treeview
- JSON Viewer.

Then it worked fine.
I then reinstalled the same extensions, but now it still works fast.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).